# Laravel - Redirect after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im a bit of a newbie when it comes to Laravel so i was hoping someone could help out.

Im using the standard authentication and login stuff that ships with Laravel so theres nothing fancy going on, but what i want to do is check in the DB to see if a few fields are completed ( name, address, postcode ) .... If they are, then the user gets redirected to the dashboard, but if they aren't, the user will get redirected to the profile page to fill out the rest of their information.

Im guessing i should put something in my routes.php file in the

```
Route::post('login', function
```

part, but how do i check for the fields?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have authenticated the user using `Auth::check` you'll be able to grab the authenticated user with `Auth::user`.

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if ($user->email == '' || $user->address == '')
    {
        return Redirect::to('user/profile');
    }

    return Redirect::to('home');
}
```

You just need to check the fields you want on the user to make sure they are there. If they're not then redirect them to the profile page. If they are redirect them to the home page or somewhere else.

Comment: Perfect, thank you ... I didnt know about the Auth::user() thing, that makes things so much easier. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way

```
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {
        return Redirect::to('users/dashboard');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('users/profile');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
if (Auth::guest()) 
{
    //user is not authenticated or logged in;
    return Redirect::to('login');
}else{
    //user is authenticated and logged in;
    return Redirect::to('profile');
}
```